# Tokenizing buffer segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, buffer, tokenize, strtok

So I'm guessing I'm missing something fairly simple here but I am trying to read a file line by line, tokenizing the buffer as I go. I have pasted the basics of what I'm trying to do with my code. I have never had issue with strtok, so I'm guessing it has to do with the buffer that I'm using. Any nudges in the right direction? I read that strtok isn't a great option, but it's the only thing I'm familiar with (I suppose I could write my own function)
It reads the first token as it's supposed to every time. It doesn't seg fault until I try to find the second token with "strtok(NULL," ");"

I don't know why this was downvoted as a duplicate. Yes, there are answers out there that tell the basics of what I'm trying to do, but I want to understand the problem, not just cut and paste." I'd prefer to know WHY there is a seg fault and why my code is behaving as it does. No need to downvote when I'm asking specific questions not pointed out directly in other posts.

```
const char *file = "path/to/file/file.txt";
void tokenize();

//Eventually file will be command line opt
FILE *open_file(const char *file);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    tokenize();
}

void tokenize()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = open_file(file);
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];

    while(fgets(buffer,BUFSIZ,fp) != NULL)
    {
        //puts("========================================");
        //puts(buffer);
        //puts("========================================");

        char *data = strdup(buffer);
        char *token;
        token = strtok(data, " ");
        //puts(token);
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");

            puts("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            puts(token);
            puts("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        }
    }
fclose(fp)
}

FILE *open_file(const char *file)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file, "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
    }
    return fp;
}
```

Comment: I had some specific questions in this post, not a generic "hey, how do I do this, gimme code." I don't think there is anything wrong with posting similar questions. I am trying to understand my code, not just to copy and paste

Comment: Do you have 2 tokens in each line? Your code expects so and also check if strtok returns NULL.

Comment: Yeah, for whatever reason I didn't include that in my code above but I have it...edited now

Comment: As indicated by dbush in his answer, it's the puts() that segfaults. But on a sidenote, this is also a memory leak. Why do you strdup() the whole buffer? Let strtok() work on it (it's scratch anyways) and strdup() the tokens as needed...

Answer (score 3):

Your `while` loop checks that `token` is not NULL, but then modifies it in the first line of the loop before using it.  The second call to `strtok()` should be at the end of the loop:

```
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        puts("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        puts(token);
        puts("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

Also, don't forget to `free(data)` at the bottom of your outer `while` loop.  Otherwise, you have a memory leak.

Comment: ... segfault because the result of the `strtok()` within OP's loop was used before it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a memory leak with

```
char *data = strdup(buffer);
```

`strdup` uses `malloc` to allocate memory for the dup string, which it is your responsibility to `free`. But, you don't, and in every loop you overwrite the previous allocated pointer with another one, resulting in **memory leak**.

Not really an answer, I re-edited a false answer so downvote as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! Here is my solution

```
while(fgets(buffer,BUFSIZ,fp) != NULL)
{
    char *token;
    token = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        **if(token != NULL)**
        {
            printf("%s\n", token);
        }
    }

}

fclose(fp);
```

As was indicated in other answers, the problem wasn't tokenizing a NULL value, it was in trying to print a NULL value. All was well in the world after I added the check if(token != NULL) within the while loop

Comment: Should not `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` be _after_ the `printf()` and then the `if(token != NULL)` is not needed?